# Merge Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

```
A               B   C       D       E   F   G   H
ACC'L SCIENCE   0.5 TRUE    557092  87  87      
ACC'L SCIENCE   0.5 TRUE    557092          88  88
ART             0.5 TRUE    557092  98  98      
ENGLISH 6       0.5 TRUE    557092  88  88      
ENGLISH 6       0.5 TRUE    557092          87  87
GIRLS PE        0.5 TRUE    557092  100 100     
GIRLS PE        0.5 TRUE    557092          94  94
```

I have the above 7 rowsin an excel file. I'm trying to check if consecutive columns have the same value, they should be merged into one row. The formula I'm attempting would create the following data

```
A               B   C       D       E   F   G   H
ACC'L SCIENCE   0.5 TRUE    557092  87  87  88  88  
ART             0.5 TRUE    557092  98  98      
ENGLISH 6       0.5 TRUE    557092  88  88  87  87  
GIRLS PE        0.5 TRUE    557092  100 100 94  94
```

Pseudo code would look something like :

```
=IF(A1 = A2),--> G1,H1 = G2, H2
```

I have to then also account for line skips -- like the art class. Would using an 'IF' statement like this to check constraints be an efficient method here ?

The problem with IF seems to be that it returns a Boolean when I really just want it to merge. Is there a sleek non-VBA way to do this ? I've found some good VBA options with similar data -- but seems there would be a way not to have to break it out. I know of MATCH and INDEX, but haven't come up with a way to just merge them out.

I tried an array MATCH - INDEX formula but it was returning odd values -- I inserted a new column so as not to mess with the data --Tried to basically merge the numbers into a single row.

```
MATCH($A$2:$A$7, INDEX(E2 & F2, $G$2:$G$7 & $H$2:$H$7))
```

I'm pretty new to excel, though I've done some python. Any pointer in the right direction, I would appreciate.

Comment: From what I can tell, Remove duplicates will delete the row, but I need to keep the data at the end of the row and merge it, basically. If I do a remove duplicate on column A, won't it completely delete all data from rows 2, 5, and 7?

Comment: You write "I have the above 7 columns in an excel file. I'm trying to check if consecutive columns have the same value, they should be merged into one row." I think you mean "I have the above 7 **rows** in an excel file. I'm trying to check if consecutive **rows** have the same value, they should be merged into one row."

Comment: Which columns should be checked for identical values? Only column A or both columns A, B, C and D?

Comment: Columns A & D ideally -- sorry forgot to include that. Also you are correct -- the above 7 rows. I'll edit that

Comment: roughly 1,000 -- they are student number -- unique student numbers -- The above file is for one student -- I probably should have explained that better in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are probably easier ways to do this than this, but my first idea would be a 2-step process:

In cell `I1`, say, put in the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$7,MATCH(1,(--($A$1:$A$7=$A1))*(--(A$1:A$7<>"")),0)),"")
```

and **enter it as an array formula** by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

You can then drag this down and across as needed.

(This formula is basically saying that so long as the values in column A match, to pull in the first non-empty row's value along with it.)

Now, you can Copy, Paste Special > Values and then use `Data` > `Remove Duplicates` to remove the duplicate rows.

Like I said, t's probably not THE most elegant solution, but it should do the trick!!

Hope that helps!!

**UPDATE:**

---

Given the comment of needing BOTH columns A and D to match, try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$7,MATCH(1,(--($A$1:$A$7=$A1))*(--($D$1:$D$7=$D1))*(--(A$1:A$7<>"")),0)),"")
```

Comment: I should have explained better -- but I need to check not only against column A, also column D -- I've tried rearranging the formula to no avail -- it was close, but it was overwriting rows 2-7 with the contents of row 1

Comment: Thanks for the help -- They do not match, though. Column A is class name, Column D is student number -- completely different fields -- just an extra check to make sure not only is the class the same, but the student is the same as well.

Comment: I'm confused... Why are you saying the updated formula doesn't work then?? All it's saying is "bring in the first non blank cell where column A mtaches my column A and column D matches my column D" ... How is that different from what you're looking for?

Comment: You did it ! Wow I apologize -- I input the formula and it wasn't giving me the two furthest columns -- It was only filling in the first two -- I re-applied it and it literally works exactly as I'd hoped. Thank you very much. The syntax was lost on me -- I couldn't really read what was going on -- also at work so multi-tasking. This was it. Thank you John.

Answer (score 1):

If sorted by D and then A, Subtotal with a little fiddling may suit. Use Sum on E, F, G and H for each change in A. Filter and select A Contains... `Total`. Fill first visible non-header row with `=Bx` in B where `x` is one less than the current row number. Copy across to D and down to suit. Unfilter, select all Copy, Paste Special Values over the top. Select A Does Not Contain... `Total` and delete all visible except header. Replace `Total` in ColumnA with nothing.